# What do the stamp marks say on these three teapots?

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

I'm not quite sure on the orientation of the stamps, I can flip them in a image editor if I need to let me know. The teapots have multiple stamps on each one so I grouped each of them into one picture for each pot. Thank you very much for any help you have as to what the names are.

[image: one]

[image: two]

[image: three]

Comment: I'm only sure about the right one in the second row - 煌.

Comment: The left one in the second row, though appearing to be a single character, should be actually two characters 宜興 stacked vertically. Note that 宜興 (simplified 宜兴) is a Chinese city famous for making teapots, especially 紫砂茶壶.

Comment: Oh I see now it's just a stylized version of writing 宜興, how unusual I've never seen any marked like that.

Comment: Here's a photo of that one if you'd like to see it. [https://imgur.com/a/EWrAmCs](https://imgur.com/a/EWrAmCs)

Comment: The first seems to be a flipped image of X華; the second, a flipped 惠

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

> 惠　小（華）

[image]

> 宐（宜）（興）　煌

[image]

> Suspected: （新）仁　座　座仁製
>
> Confirmed: Ａ　Ｂ　ＢＡ製
>
> I see:
>
> - Ｂ: 座（广 + 坐）
>
>   <kbd>古文
>   [image]
>   說文解字</kbd>
>   　<kbd>今
>   楷
>   [image]</kbd>
> - Ａ: 仁
>
>   [image]